# Excel Find the max length of characters after decimal in a given column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to find a way to get the max number of characters after the decimal place in a given column. For example

[image: Max chars after decimal]

I found this to get the max length in a column (using ctrl+shift+enter):

```
=MAX(LEN(A1:A5))
```

And this formula to get the number of characters after the decimal for a single cell:

```
=LEN(A1)-FIND(".",A1)
```

But I need to combine the two into a single formula so that I don't need another column of data. Is this possible without VBA?

Edit, one example I might encounter would be 99.999 vs 100.12 that I'd need to differentiate between and result in a length of 3 characters after the decimal.

Comment: If any of your data is the result of formulas, you may have some surprising results and need to use VBA.  Otherwise, so long as the format is `General`, you can use  `=MAX(LEN(A1:A5)-FIND(".",A1:A5&"."))` confirmed by holding down `ctrl+shift` while hitting `enter`

Comment: Thanks. That almost works. It does return -1 if all the values are integers but I should be able to use an if to fix that.

Comment: Just add a zero to the formula:  `=MAX(LEN(A1:A5)-FIND(".",A1:A5&"."),0)`  I will post this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If any of your data is the result of formulas, you may have some surprising results and need to use VBA. Otherwise, so long as the format is General, you can use

```
=MAX(LEN(A1:A5)-FIND(".",A1:A5&"."),0)
```

confirmed by holding down ctrl+shift while hitting enter

Answer (score 1):

You can use Array Formulas in conjunction with some of your original suggestions to accomplish this. The formula in the example you provided would be:

```
{=MAX(IFERROR(LEN(B1:B3)-FIND(".",B1:B3),0))}
```

Some notes:

The "IFERROR" function is used to return a 0 to the MAX function if the "." is not found in the string

Array formulas can be entered into excel by entering the text "=MAX(IFERROR(LEN(B1:B3)-FIND(".",B1:B3),0))" into the formula bar and pressing ctrl+shift+enter (at which point the curly brackets will appear)

Applying this formula should yeild the following results for your sample inputs:

[Sample Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkU9L.png)